# Free ASP.NET CMS for library

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system

We have library website written in classic ASP that allows to browse and search by multiple (50+) filter criterias (author, publication year, ISSN ... ). There are lots of security holes and we have only one developer who hardly maintain this ASP-site with some minor features for last 3 years. 
There are two common user groups - administrators (librarians) and students (5000+) who have books on hands and search for them.

We don't want to rewrite site from scratch, just to use standard free CMS (.net based) and migrate library data and user accounts with minimum effort. What CMS will you suggest?

What do you think of SharePoint? It has out-of-the-box Visual Studio 2010 support so it looks promising (but we have no experience with this CMS)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/) in the past and was pretty satisfied with it. Another one to try is [Umbraco](http://umbraco.org/). Also, this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems#ASP.NET) has a huge list of CMS systems broken down by language and cost.

Comment: Thank you, what's you opinion about SharePoint?

Comment: I wish we were using SharePoint. I saw a demo of it (the Enterprise version) and it looked really nice. Currently we're using one of the proprietary ASP.NET CMS listed in the Wikipedia article (not gonna name which one), but I am less than satisfied with it.... I didn't even know SharePoint has a free version.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Foundation (formerly SharePoint Services) could certainly be customized to meet your needs. However, its learning curve will be much steeper than some of the other options mentioned, and it doesn't sound like you would use enough of its features (collaboration, document management, etc) to justify that additional cost.

Comment: We have some thoughts to migrate another system, so document management part may be demanded. We have about 2 monthes to start migration project.

Comment: SharePoint could very well be a good fit, I would just warn against trying to use it to avoid custom development - you will likely end up with more code rather than less. For example, migrating data into SharePoint requires custom code rather than simple SQL scripts.

Comment: SharePoint is a piece of shit. Dumb ass managers think sharepoint does everything

Answer (score 0):

[MojoPortal](http://www.mojoportal.com/home.aspx). Free .net based CMS. [More Info.](http://www.mojoportal.com/about.aspx)

Comment: Ok, I'll investigate MojoPortal a bit later. What do you think about SharePoint (version that is minimized but free)?

Answer (score 0):

Use Dotnetnuke. It has years of development effort a lot of lot plugin modules and a vibrant community.

Comment: Thank you, I'll definitely investigate Nuke in a month